# What is 去意 here?

Tags: meaning

I think I understand the first part of this sentence, but sometimes Chinese surprises me completely, so I'd like to check. The text discusses 2 pilots who quit their jobs. Have I read it correctly, or completely wrong?

见两人去意已决，航空公司提出，10年间公司每年都送他们出国学习，分别花去培训费84.9万元和112.8万元。

见两人去意已决 = see 2 people go-idea already decide

= Seeing that the 2 pilots had already decided to go,

Maybe better '见‘ here means 'being aware, aware, realizing, understanding'

I really like the way Chinese can do this '去意‘, so condensed, so direct, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Correct and correct.

Comment: Yes, it's the beauty of Chinese!

Comment: Could someone please provide a full translation?

Comment: Really is a beautiful language! I translate it as: "Realizing that the 2 pilots had already decided to leave, the airline reckoned up, in the space of 10 years they had sent the pilots abroad every year for further training, which, individually， cost 849 000 Yuan and 1 128 000 Yuan respectively."

Comment: You are all correct. However, the whole sentence does not make sense to me. If they decided to leave, why spent money and gave them further training? 去意已决 as you translated, decided to leave, no room for negotiating. If it is 去意强烈 (strongly inclined to leave), then it makes a lot more sense

Comment: @jf328 I guess you could say it's a different between "They've decided to leave" vs "They have left".  It's truly no room for negotiatin only if they're gone right?

Comment: translation: Realizing that the two has determined to leave, the airline mentioned, within (the last, implied) ten years the company has sent them overseas to study yearly, having spent 849 thousand dollars and 1.128 million dollars respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are exactly correct!

去意 means 去 的 意思

which is exactly "the decision to go"

You are also understanding 见 the right way.

Many condensed and direct words you see are used as regular words in old Chinese. Many are not used in modern oral Chinese, but definitely a lot in wr